# StartsWith behaves differently on different machines

Tags: c#

A small test prog that works as expected on my dev machine (Win7 x64) behaves completely differently on a Server 2012 machine. Can anyone tell me why, please?

This is the code:

```
class Program
{

    static void w(string msg = "")
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(msg);
    }

    static void w(string fmt, params object[] p)
    {
        var s = string.Format(fmt, p);
        w(s);
    }

    public static string BytesToString(byte[] barr)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.AppendFormat("Length : {0}      ", barr.Length);

        for (int i = 0; i < barr.Length; ++i)
        {
            byte b = barr[i];
            sb.AppendFormat("[{0:0000}] {1:X2}    ", i, b);
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string test_string = "123456789";

        // Remove the BOM (Byte Order Marker)
        byte[] baUTF8 = Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble();
        string _byteOrderMarkUtf8 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(baUTF8);

        w("UTF8 BOM length : {0}", _byteOrderMarkUtf8.Length);
        w(BytesToString(baUTF8));

        if (test_string.StartsWith(_byteOrderMarkUtf8))
        {
            w("Test string starts with BOM for UTF8");
            w("Removing UTF8 BOM");
            w("Length : {0}", test_string.Length);
            test_string = test_string.Remove(0, _byteOrderMarkUtf8.Length);
            w("Length : {0}", test_string.Length);
        }
        else
        {
            w("Test string does not start with BOM for UTF8");
        }

        w();

        byte[] baUTF16 = Encoding.Unicode.GetPreamble();
        string _byteOrderMarkUNC = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(baUTF16);

        w("UTF16 BOM length : {0}", _byteOrderMarkUNC.Length);
        w(BytesToString(baUTF16));

        if (test_string.StartsWith(_byteOrderMarkUNC))
        {
            w("Test string starts with BOM for UTF16");
            w("Removing UTF16 BOM");
            w("Length : {0}", test_string.Length);
            test_string = test_string.Remove(0, _byteOrderMarkUNC.Length);
            w("Length : {0}", test_string.Length);
        }
        else
        {
            w("Test string does not start with BOM for UTF16");
        }

        w();
        w("Hit RETURN to end the program.");
        w();

        System.Console.ReadLine();
    }

} // class Program
```

These are the (expected) results on my machine:

```
UTF8 BOM length : 1
Length : 3      [0000] EF    [0001] BB    [0002] BF
Test string does not start with BOM for UTF8

UTF16 BOM length : 1
Length : 2      [0000] FF    [0001] FE
Test string does not start with BOM for UTF16

Hit RETURN to end the program.
```

These are the wacky-doodle results on the Server 2012 machine:

```
UTF8 BOM length : 1
Length : 3      [0000] EF    [0001] BB    [0002] BF
Test string starts with BOM for UTF8
Removing UTF8 BOM
Length : 9
Length : 8

UTF16 BOM length : 1
Length : 2      [0000] FF    [0001] FE
Test string starts with BOM for UTF16
Removing UTF16 BOM
Length : 8
Length : 7

Hit RETURN to end the program.
```

Any comments gratefully received.

Thanks,

Adam